# Installing Ubuntu on external 1TB HDD alongside windows 10 on SSD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd, windows-10, external-hdd

My PC is HP Laptop 15-dy0xxx with Intel core-i5, 1.60GHz CPU, 12GB RAM and only 238GB SSD (no HDD) and recently took a transcend 1TB External HDD. It has been installed windows 10 by default. Now I want to install Ubuntu for academic research purpose (alongside Windows 10). Now 2 question..

1. Where should I install Ubuntu, on SSD or external HDD ?
2. Can you tell me the procedure ?

Comment: To give a helpful answer: What kind of research? How often will you be visiting the Linux system and what will you do there?  How much room do you have left on the SSD? Have you considered a VM?

Comment: In details, academic research on blockchain technology where some web api and database related work also needed. Linux will have to use almost everyday for coding, making reports and making slideshows etc. SSD free about 127 GB. No I'm not familiar with VM, suggest me !

Comment: Take a look at VirtualBox. `sudo apt install virtualbox`. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox but there is a lot of info on it. It is a way of installing and running Ubuntu as a file on your system. You can configure it to install the system to your HDD, You have 12GB RAM so you can easily give your VM 4 which will be plenty for perfectly acceptable performance. You can run Windows and Ubuntu at the same time!

Comment: I just checked on the VM but need to know some other things. Can I use the ex HDD for windows too where I intend to use VM ?

Comment: Other queries.... If I allocate 4 GB for VM, with the other 8 GB for the windows could be lacked in performance when software development ? Can I use the VM Ubuntu environment for software development too ?

Comment: You could run development processes in Windows and in Ubuntu at the same time. You could actually give the VM 8 GB and Windows would still run. Or could run the Ubuntu in 2GB. When you are not running the VM there is no loss to Windows resources whatsoever. Think of the VM as a Windows application that runs Ubuntu. It is much less invasive or permanent than dual boot.

Comment: Yes you can use the HDD for windows. The VM is simply a file on that drive same as any other file. It does not own any part of your machine. It's just the same as any other application file. Understand that a VM makes no change to your system in the way that a dual boot does. On one of my machines I have three VMs running at the same time.

Comment: One last query and thanks for all of these... I think Hyper-V of Windows will be a good choice. As you are experienced about VMs, tell me that is Hyper-v is a good choice for me or Oracle VM VirtualBox ? Is Hyper-V is bit complex or similar to other VMs ?

Comment: I have no experience with Hyper-V.